# Development of hybird mobile app

Tags: mobile, phonegap

I want to start work on development of Hybird mobile app that access the database already developed database. I want to ask which framework is easy to use for the task and which tutorials will help me.

Comment: You can go with ionic https://ionicframework.com/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

**Top 5 hybrid Mobile App Frameworks in 2018 – Choose the best one for you**

***1. [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)***

React native is a rising open source platform & the future of Hybrid Mobile App Development. Basically, it based on JavaScript & allows you to build a mobile app using JavaScript. Primarily, it gives more attention to the view part of the app. Some well-known apps built using React Native are – Facebook, Walmart, UberEATS&Instagram etc.

> Features :

Offers a lot of Plugins.
Great Response Time.
Extremely fast.
Compatible with iPhone & Android
Reusable Components.
React Native is open-source.
Saves the time of the developers.
Powerful Performance.
Less Memory Usage.
Just write once & Utilize react native UI components to an existing app code. You do not need to rewrite again.
Completely support Node.Js

***2. [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/)***

Ionic is the most popular & favorite framework on the list for the hybrid app development.It is an HTML5 mobile app development framework which is designed with native-styled UI elements. It is used to build hybrid mobile apps.The cool thing about it is that Iconic has a rich set of advanced features such as mobile components, interactive paradigms, typography, and an extensible base theme that makes the job easier.

> Features :

Expertise in the advanced technologies such as CSS, HTML AngularJS or Javascript components.
Support for Angular material design.
Wrapping Angular Framework.
The Ionic framework is easily maintainable.
Scalable.
Easy to read.
Open source & free.

***3. [Framework 7](https://framework7.io/)***

Framework 7 is known to make the web development process agile. The coolest thing about Framework 7 is, unlike other hybrid frameworks, it has no external dependency on tools like Angular or React.

> Features :

Super easy & comfortable to use. You just have to know the CSS, HTML or JavaScript.
Open Source.
A Lots of UI elements and widgets.
Powerful performance.
Use a lot of animation.
Totally free from license fee.

***4. [PhoneGap](https://phonegap.com/)***

Being mobile-centric and open-source; Phonegap development is one of the most popular application development frameworks.It is one of the most popular frameworks which is used by many experienced developers. With Phonegap framework one can deliver robust and feature-rich applications which are fully customized hybrid applications that works efficiently across multiple platforms and reach large scale audience in lesser time.

> Features :

Supports iOS, Android, Palm, BlackBerry, Symbian, and iPad &Single code development for all of the platforms
Built on technologies like HTML JavaScript and CSS3 that gives a rich experience
Open-source cross-platform.
Native Functionality.
Can be extended with native plug-ins & let developers add more functionalities.
5. Onsen UI
In short time, Onsen UI made a mark for its versatility & flexibility. It has become a strong competitor to Ionic. It’s an open source framework which is now fully independent.

> Advice

You can begin with PhoneGap it's easy if you know some basic (Js-html-css-jquery ..).

[Tutorial](http://docs.phonegap.com/references/developer-app/) for Phonegap